# Publish imu topics using logged data

Tags: imu, navigation, gps, rostopic--pub, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a txt file which contains sensors (GPS, Accelerometer, Gyroscope, Magnetic Field) reading along with a time stamp.

How do I write a node to publish these data as topics?

Ultimately I want to use the robot_localization package to fuse all these data.

Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/234579/publish-imu-topics-using-logged-data/) by [b-sriram](https://answers.ros.org/users/26278/b-sriram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2016-05-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll just need to read the text file, parse the data, create ROS messages with the data, and publish them. As long as they adhere to ROS standards and are [supported](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization#Features), you can use `robot_localization`.

---

Originally posted by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) with karma: 13689 on 2016-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0